# CoreGraphics object autoreleased too many times

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, autorelease

Upon analyzing my app, Xcode gave me an alert showing that their was a potential leak of an object stored into 'colorSpace' (last line of the code below):

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

So, I added the following line:

```
CFAutorelease(context);
```

And analyzed again. This time, I got an alert in the second line below of "object autoreleased too many times (within a call to 'CGPointMake'):

```
case SWShadowDirectionUp:
     startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 0.5);
     endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 0.5);
                break;
```

Below is where the colorSpace variable is used:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
NSArray *colors = @[ (__bridge id)self.startColor.CGColor, (__bridge id)self.endColor.CGColor ];
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, locations);
CFAutorelease(colorSpace);
```

However, I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong, or how to fix it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't shown your usage of the `colorSpace` variable. The static analyzer will typically note leaks at the end of the scope (where the object will leak) instead of upon usage or declaration of the object.

Comment: Does the warning go away if you try using   `CGColorSpaceRelease()`?

Comment: @JackWu Yes it does, but now I have a warning of Call to function 'CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count

Comment: I'm not sure what that's about but looking at your same code try replacing all your `CFAutorelease`'s ie. `CGContextRelease()`, etc

Comment: When I use `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` and follow it up with `CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace)`, I get no warnings or static analyzer messages. You should probably just use explicit releases instead of autorelease.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @IanMacDonald. Would you mind showing me an example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure what you've done wrong in your source because you haven't included the entire scope of `colorSpace`. Here is what I have tried and the static analyzer does not complain:

```
- (UIImage *)decompressImage:(UIImage *)image {
  CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
  size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
  size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8,
                                               width * 4, colorSpace,
                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  if (!context)
    return image;

  CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), imageRef);
  CGImageRef decompressedImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
  CGContextRelease(context);

  UIImage *decompressedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:decompressedImageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
  CGImageRelease(decompressedImageRef);
  return decompressedImage;
}
```

Just make sure you have a `Release` for every `Create` before the end of the scope.